# How to create a date and time picker in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any android widget that enable to pick the date and the time at the same time ?
I already use the basic [time picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html) and [date picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html).

But they are not that sexy and user friendly (I found). Do you know if a widget including both date and time exists?

Thanks a lot,
Luc

Comment: There is a Github library for date and time picker: [AndroidDateTimePicker](https://github.com/Fei-Sheng-Wu/AndroidDateTimePicker).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is nothing built into Android that offers this.

EDIT: Andriod now offers built-in pickers. Check [@Oded answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22626706/1397821)

Comment: I know this response is more than a year old, but I think this response should be updated. The DateSlider library referenced by Rabi all the way below seems to be perfect for this.

Comment: I agree this answer should be updated because that's an awesome widget. However the code pointed to by Rabi is already a bit outdated and contains some deprecated methods e.g. `showDialog`. Perhaps something more current will come along soon.

Comment: Actually answer is correct and shouldn't be updated. Even if AndroidDateSlider exist, there is nothing built into Android that offers that feature.

Comment: Am I the only one baffled at the fact that Google doesn't even support one of the most widely used controls in any business applications out there?

Answer (score 91):

Put both `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` in a layout XML.

**date_time_picker.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:calendarViewShown="true"
        android:spinnersShown="false"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/time_picker"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Set"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code:

```
final View dialogView = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.date_time_picker, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();

dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

         DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
         TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

         Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),
                            datePicker.getMonth(),
                            datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                            timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                            timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

         time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
         alertDialog.dismiss();
    }});
alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Brilliant example, thanks. One point... you probably want to have alertDialog.dismiss(); at the end of the onClick implementation.

Comment: Can't pick year in this example.

Comment: Just one problem...when using in android L the date and time picker do not fit on the screen..so i put the linearLayout in a scrollView ...Now the problem is that when i try to change the time the layout scrolls because of the scrollView..Any solution to this

Comment: please help , it is not fit in landscape mode, how to fix it

Comment: @Awadesh , For landscape, you'll have to create another xml like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4858052/710284

Comment: it is working but when i switch from landscape mode to portrait or vice-versa it is not changing automatically

Comment: Android 6.0+ this layout looks ugly ;( https://static.pychat.org/photo/f1qRFo31_Screenshot_20170214-123713.png

Comment: But they are overlapping each other, maybe if you used scrollview as a root layout it would be much better

Answer (score 82):

Use this function it will enable you to pic date and time one by one then set it to global variable date. No library no XML.

```
Calendar date;
public void showDateTimePicker() {
   final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
   date = Calendar.getInstance();
   new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            date.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    Log.v(TAG, "The choosen one " + date.getTime());
                }
            }, currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();
       }
   }, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DATE)).show();
}
```

Comment: One of the simplest way

Comment: Call requires API level 24.

Comment: How do I get the datePicker object? I want to disabled past dates.

Answer (score 29):

[image: combined DatePicker and TimePicker in DialogFragment for Android]

I created a [library](https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker) to do this. It also has customizable colors!

It's very simple to use.

First you create a listener:

```
private SlideDateTimeListener listener = new SlideDateTimeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateTimeSet(Date date)
    {
        // Do something with the date. This Date object contains
        // the date and time that the user has selected.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateTimeCancel()
    {
        // Overriding onDateTimeCancel() is optional.
    }
};
```

Then you create and show the dialog:

```
new SlideDateTimePicker.Builder(getSupportFragmentManager())
    .setListener(listener)
    .setInitialDate(new Date())
    .build()
    .show();
```

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: really good one ! saved my time ! thanks ! However, i had to clone the code, because i think gradle dependency string is not valid ?

Comment: @k2ibegin the git page of project says to import the whole module or "clone the code", thats the point, he didn't publish his awesome date-time-picker in any repository. JDJ nice work man, great lib.

Comment: @JDJ sorry, but i haven't been able to add your library to my project, could you explain how ?

Comment: @Kuriel How can i add the library ?

Comment: **Step 1** download the whole project by clicking "Clone or download" and then "download ZIP" **Step 2** extract zip content, or just the ZIP\SlideDateTimePicker-master\ **slideDateTimePicker** folder and copy that folder to your **root** folder container of your existing project where you want to add the plugin. **Step 3** add the Dependency via Gradle with **compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')** OR with Android Studio: File > New > Import  Project and select the extracted folder and configure project import normally accept and next and finish.

Comment: @JDJ we have a bug, on Lollipop or Marshmallow the native DatePicker and TimePicker is not shown, instead shows the pre-lollipop components.

Comment: @JDC I tried lots of things but could not change theme. How can we implement Material Design?

Comment: Error:(30, 0) Project with path ':slideDateTimePicker' could not be found in project ':app'.
<a href="openFile:/Users/ruchirbaronia/AndroidStudioProjects/FeatureFive/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: For adding the library manually, I found that **settings.gradle** needs to be updated with a reference to the lib, like so: `include ':app', .. ':slideDateTimePicker'` .. thanks to details in *"Method 1"* here : https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Comment: Please note I believe this library no longer works, and has been abandoned. https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker/issues/59

Comment: How do you customize the color of horizontal date and time divider? When you use the setIndicatorColor(), it only changes the color header, not date/time divider

Comment: The original project has been forked and updated: https://github.com/yulmaso/SlideDateTimePicker

Answer (score 21):

Call the time picker dialog in the `DatePicker` update time method. It'll not be called at the same time but when you press `DatePicker` set button. The time picker dialog will open.
The method is given below.

```
package com.android.date;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class datepicker extends Activity {

    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
    private TextView mTimeDisplay;
    private Button mPickTime;

    private int mhour;
    private int mminute;

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mDateDisplay =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
        mPickDate =(Button)findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
        mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timepicker);

        //Pick time's click event listener
        mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        //PickDate's click event listener 
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    //-------------------------------------------update date---//    
    private void updateDate() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mDay).append("/")
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
    }

      //-------------------------------------------update time---//    
    public void updatetime() {
        mTimeDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                        .append(pad(mhour)).append(":")
                        .append(pad(mminute))); 
    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);


    //Datepicker dialog generation  

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDate();
            }
        };


     // Timepicker dialog generation
        private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mhour = hourOfDay;
                    mminute = minute;
                    updatetime();
                }
            };

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                            mDateSetListener,
                            mYear, mMonth, mDay);

            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                        mTimeSetListener, mhour, mminute, false);

            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

the main.xml is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timepicker"
        android:text="Change Time" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/datepicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:text="Change the date"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 15):

I also wanted to combine a DatePicker and a TimePicker.
So I create an API to handle both in one interface! :)

https://github.com/Kunzisoft/Android-SwitchDateTimePicker

[image]

You can also use [SublimePicker](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker)

Comment: Very nice elegant solution.  Works great.  A few small details I ran into .. 1) The AM/PM label was getting truncated, so I had to set a smaller font size  in style: `<item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>`  and remove the bold setting.  2) looks like `setDefaultDateTime(..)` must be called or you get a runtime exception .. so I call that with just `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` as the parameter.  Best github project for a date picker I have seen so far - thanks for sharing it

Answer (score 13):

The URLs you link to show how to pop up a dialog with a time picker and another dialog with a date picker.  However you need to be aware that you can use those UI widgets directly in your own layout.  You could build your own dialog that includes both a TimePicker and DatePicker in the same view, thus accomplishing what I think you are looking for.

In other words, instead of using TimePickerDialog and DatePickerDialog, just use the UI widgets <s>[TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html)</s> and <s>[DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)</s> directly in your own dialog or activity.

Comment: I agree @Jaydeep Khamar's solution is not what is asked for, those are opening two separate dialogs. It would be better to see basic sample code where this is already combined.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same problem in one of my projects and have decided to make a custom widget that has both the date and the time picker in one user-friendly dialog. You can get the source code along with an example at http://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/. The code is licensed under Apache 2.0.

Answer (score 6):

I forked, updated, refactored and mavenized the android-dateslider project. It is on Github now:

https://github.com/casidiablo/date-slider

Comment: do you have an example on how to use this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of `DatePicker library` [wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

- First show DatePicker.

  ```
  private void showDatePicker() {
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
  DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
          HomeActivity.this,
          now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
          now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
          now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
  );
  dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Choose Date:");
  }
  ```
- Then `onDateSet callback store date & show TimePicker`

  ```
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
  filter.setDate(cal.getTime());
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          showTimePicker();
      }
  },500);
  }
  ```
- On `onTimeSet callback` store time

  ```
   @Override
   public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  if(filter.getDate()!=null)
      cal.setTime(filter.getDate());
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

May be this tutorial link will help
http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html

Answer (score 3):

I wrote up a little widget that allows you to pick both date and time.

[DateTimeWidget](https://github.com/techartist/DateTimeWidget)

[image]

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the necro post, but is it possible to import your widget into my .xml layout file?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the [android-wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) project that comes pretty close the the UIDatePicker dialog of iOS.

It provides a vertical slider to pick anything(including date and time). If you prefer horizontal slider, the DateSlider referenced by Rabi is better.

Comment: Broken link.  Here's a [fork of android-wheel](https://github.com/maarek/android-wheel).

Answer (score 1):

I have create a alert dialog which combine Date picker and Time picker.
You can get code at https://github.com/nguyentoantuit/android
Note: DateTimePicker is a library

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more compact version of Jaydeep's idea of showing one dialog after the other. I like this solution because it has no dependencies.

```
        Date value = new Date();
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(value);
        new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, 
                        int y, int m, int d) {
                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);

                    // now show the time picker
                    new TimePickerDialog(NoteEditor.this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, 
                                    int h, int min) {
                                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
                                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                                value = cal.getTime();
                            }
                        }, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
                            cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
                 }
            }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```