# Date and time picker in one view

Tags: android, android-widget, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I wanted to know whether we can implement both date and time picker in one view...

In our iPhone app you can pick both date and time through one view. But in Android we have date picker and time picker used separately. Is there any method by which I can get values of both date and time from one view?

Comment: Already answered in StackOverflow... Have a [LOOK>>>][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055509/datetime-picker-in-android-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in widget that implements both a date and time picker. However, you can create your own custom view for that, perhaps combining the existing `DatePicker` and `TimePicker`.

Comment: Can u plz elaborate how to create a custom view. It will be helpful if you can provide an example also.