# Android: alternate layout xml for landscape mode

Tags: android, layout, resources, android-layout, orientation

How can I have one layout for landscape and one for portrait? I want to assume extra width and conserve vertical space when the user rotates the phone over sideways.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

By default, the layouts in `/res/layout` are applied to both portrait and landscape.

If you have for example

```
/res/layout/main.xml
```

you can add a new folder `/res/layout-land`, copy `main.xml` into it and make the needed adjustments.

[image: orientation]

See also http://www.androidpeople.com/android-portrait-amp-landscape-differeent-layouts and http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40792/1954 for some more options.

Comment: should i have to keep the name **layout-land** or any other word @marapet

Comment: You can't use any other word

Comment: My background image stretches out on landscape.I have layout-land and drawable-land..still it stretches out..I've tried using same image,9-patch images,mdpi,hdpi n all..still issue persists :(

Comment: what is the word for `portrait`

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd according to Android studio it is layout-port

Comment: after i create layout-land, it was invisible then i had to right click on the layout folder and select show in folder then i copied and pasted the <layout>.xml file there. then it appered in the Project explorer. thanks

Answer (score 84):

In the current version of Android Studio (v1.0.2) you can simply add a landscape layout by clicking on the button in the visual editor shown in the screenshot below. Select "Create Landscape Variation"

[image: Android Studio add landscape layout]

Comment: Except it puts a new copy in your `layout-land` folder. Any idea how to call a layout from there? Can't use `R.layout.layout_name`. I'm trying to configure my own layouts manually upon configuration change, thanks.

Comment: @NoniA. It should detect when the phone switch to landscape and call the one from layout-land automatically.

Comment: @Distwo but the problem is, if app is running in portrait mode it will shut off, i have to keep using it in landscape to word, because there some elements I used in MainActivity.java when the class is created. People who actually made this Android are dumb founded, seriously

Comment: You need to architect your view and models properly. Here is an article about preserving data across configuration changes. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Answer (score 43):

The layouts in /res/layout are applied to both portrait and landscape, unless you specify otherwise. Let’s assume we have /res/layout/home.xml for our homepage and we want it to look differently in the 2 layout types.

1. create folder /res/layout-land (here you will keep your landscape adjusted layouts)
2. copy home.xml there
3. make necessary changes to it

[Source](http://www.tekkie.ro/quick-n-dirty/how-to-change-your-layout-in-android-landscape-portrait-mode/)

Comment: what about for 'portrait'?

Comment: What about with the new <sw> qualifiers?

Answer (score 9):

Fastest way for Android Studio 3.x.x and Android Studio 4.x.x

1.Go to the design tab of the activity layout

2.At the top you should press on the **orientation for preview** button, there is a option to create a landscape layout (check image), a new folder will be created as your xml layout file for that particular orientation

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can group your specific layout under the correct folder structure as follows.

*layout-land-target_version*

ie

**layout-land-19** // target KitKat

likewise you can create your layouts.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't see how your answer helps because this question was already answered. Maybe you could explain the benefit of the `-19` suffix? Is that helpful in any way?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain it shortly.

First, you may notice that now you should use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.html) as requested by google (see androix library).

In your android studio projet, you can provide screen-specific layouts by creating additional res/layout/ directories. One for each screen configuration that requires a different layout.

This means you have to use the **directory qualifier** in both cases :

- Android device support
- Android landscape or portrait mode

As a result, here is an exemple :

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml                # For handsets
res/layout-land/main_activity.xml           # For handsets in landscape
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml        # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw600dp-land/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets in landscape
```

You can also use qualifier with res ressources files using dimens.xml.

```
res/values/dimens.xml                # For handsets
res/values-land/dimens.xml           # For handsets in landscape
res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml        # For 7” tablets
```

res/values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="grid_view_item_height">70dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

res/values-land/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="grid_view_item_height">150dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

your_item_grid_or_list_layout.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_view_item_height"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Source : https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes