# screen orientations in Android, landscape

Tags: android, background-image, landscape, landscape-portrait

I would like to know how to modify views when the phone orientation is changed. Like for example my app works fine when you hold the phone "the normal way" but when you moove it into the landscape position then the app appearance becomes ugly:
-how to make sure the wallpaper doesn't "turn" together with the phone, here is my layout code:
name of file: list-event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
   <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:background="@drawable/fon2"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see it's just a simple list but I would like the background to stay the same. 
I put the same content for layout and layout-land I just put this same file list_event but I think I need to add some comand for the background image to be oriented in diferent way.
I hope you understand what I wrote
thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create different layouts for your views in landscape and portrait mode and put the landscape ones in `res/layout-land` and the portrait ones in `res/layout-port` (technically you only need layout and layout-{land,port} as layout is the fallback if no orientation qualifier is given).

See [the docs for more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the easiest solution, other than drawing 9-patch images.

Answer (score 1):

In your landscape layout (see Heiko's and TofferJ's answers), use **another** image, suited for the landscape layout (with the desired orientation/dimensions).

Comment: You can also provide alternative images in your res/drawable-port res/drawable-land directories. Then you don't need to reference images with different names in your layout.xml, android automatically chooses the right ones according to current orientation. Here's an example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/res/index.html

Answer (score 0):

See this post here för details: [Android: alternate layout xml for landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode)

Or check Google's tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html