# MultiScreen ListView Android does not work well when rotated

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Hello guys i have problem with my Listview . I have different layout for portrait and landscape item listview (layout and layout-land) like here :

**Item listview Layout for Portrait**

[image]

**Item listview Layout for Landscape**
[image]

this is simulation rotate from portrait to landscape

**result on portrait / not yet rotated**

[image]

**result after rotated landscape**

[image]

**Which I want after rotated**

[image]

so how to solve it ?

Comment: Might be better off using TableView and TableRow as this is almost exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me to solve a similar problem. I hope that it helps you too.

[Android: alternate layout xml for landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode)

Comment: thanks for answered, yes i'm have declare different layout (layout/xxx.xml and layout-land/xxx.xml) in my resource like that ..
but the result is like my question above :(