# Set different wallpaper for portrait and landscape android

Tags: android, landscape-portrait, android-wallpaper

I am trying to set a wallpaper, When i view it in Portrait mode then it actually sets what i see, but when i switch to landscape mode a bit gets cropped.

When i view it in landscape mode and then switch to portrait my image shifts upwards leaving a black border of about 150px because i switched from landscape to portrait.

This is because the viewport of a phone being 1920x1920 instead of the actual used size of 1080x1920. 
Is it possible to set a different wallpaper for each view (either landscape or portrait) ? without using a live wallpaper.

the viewport size is being retrieved using `mWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth()` and `mWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight()` where `mWallpaperManager` is an instance of `WallpaperManager`.

Comment: You can make different XML files for each layout. So you can basically just change the whole layout when you are in portrait or in landscape. Refer to this post on how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode

Comment: @BramDriesen That is for when you want to set it in a layoutfile. I'm trying to set it as a wallpaper

Comment: there are listeners available to notify when orientation changes. And on orientation change change the wallpaper

Comment: @Heisenberg not for the wallpaperManager

Comment: @MaximGeerinck have you found the solution?