# Can't create layout-land folder in res

Tags: android-studio

I'm going through the Big Nerd Ranch Android book which uses Eclipse. I'm using Android Studio instead. I'm just trying to create a `layout-land` folder under `res`. I've right-clicked on `res` to create a new `Directory`.

In finder on my Mac I do see that the folder was created, however the folder doesn't show in my project on Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. You can use "Create Landscape Variation" in visual editor instead of creating new directory.
If you do this you should see two files with your layout (one with "(land)"). When you open project in explorer you will find a catalog layout-land with your layout inside.

Check this link. [Create Landscape Variation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28100760/4195084)