# Android fix orientation issue on some phones

Tags: android, orientation, exif

I am having some problems with my phone camera (I am using Sony Xperia Z1 Compact) because the camera is always on Landscape mode when I launch it via the intent and therefore the photo is rotated when taken in portrait mode. This issue doesn't exist on Nexus 5. How can I solve it ? The exif returns always 0 because it's locked on landscape

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create different layouts for each portrait and landscape mode. [How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode) 
On the other hand, there might be the problem with device, test it with other apps from store.