# How to set different layouts for different orientations in a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have an activity which contain 3 fragments. 2 of them have data in a listview therefore when user rotate the screen everything is ok. but on my third fragment which contain buttons, when the user rotate the screen to landscape orientation,everything goes astray!

**my third fragment in protrait orientation**

[image: portait orientation]

**my third fragment in landscape!**

[image]

I have even tried to use scrollview but it's not working because when in landscape i don't want that big space at the middle. **i wan't 3 x 2 buttons arrangment(i have 6 buttons.) when in landscape. and i think i can only achieve that by using 2 xml layouts for my fragment.**

Question is how can i do that?

Comment: @SaiPhani      How will i then call it in my fragment because it won't be used by the entire activity but only i fragment?

Comment: you dont need to call specifically. define your layout with the same name of you 3rd fragment and append `-land` at the end. Android will call it automatically. If your fragment name is `third_fragment.xml`. create a new xml with a name `third_fragment-land.xml`. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode/4858052#4858052

Comment: @SaiPhani let me try right now and i will tell you the results. don't go away(i beg you :) )

Comment: @SaiPhani      great guidance, great help. i finally achieved what i want. thanks a lot man. (see my outcome (answer) below)

Comment: Happy that it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Make another layout folder `layout-land` under `res` and create landscape orientation layout file under this folder

Comment: how will i then call it(or use it) in my fragment ?

Comment: Don't do anything, android do the rest.

Comment: @gikarasojokinene you dont need to call specifically. define your layout with the same name of you 3rd fragment and append `-land` at the end. Android will call it automatically. If your fragment name is `third_fragment.xml`. create a new xml with a name `third_fragment-land.xml`. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode/4858052#4858052

Answer (score 1):

After great help from **sai Phani(see his comments above)**. i finally achieved my objective which was to create a landscape layout for my fragment by doing the following.

- Create a folder under `src\main\res` and call it `layout-land`
- copy your fragment layout xml (e.g `peoplefragment.xml`) which is in `src\main\res\layout` and paste it into `src\main\res\layout-land` folder. **Don't change the file name!**
- Once you have pasted it, you can change the views alignment the way you would like them t appear on landscape. for my sutuation, i wanted them to appear like this in landscape

[image: landscape orientation]

Comment: Is it working, If it changed orientation dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You may design your layouts that looks good for both portrait and landscape but you may customize for both orientation.
Look at SO link on the same issue @ [Android: alternate layout xml for landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode). The idea is simply to create folder names the correct way specified in Google documentation.

A good Google webpage is @ [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), search for "Using configuration qualifiers". There is a table stating Orientation and the folder names to use.