# Android: reusable layout file for different activities with multiple orientations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation, reusability, android-inflate

Is there a way to reuse a single activity layout-file (one orientation) for another activity with two orientations.

for example I have the MainActivity with one layout-file that just shows everything fullscreen:

**activity_generic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_generic);
```

And then I have SettingsActivity which should show everything fullscreen in portrait-mode and everything splitscreen in landscape-mode.

**activity_settings.xml**

```
//use activity_generic.xml somehow
```

**activity_settings.xml (land)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_left"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_right"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
```

Of course there is a way to fix this problem within code by checking the orientation and inflating another layout based on that, but it feels kind of hacky. I tried to use an include tag but it didn't work. Does anybody else know the solution to this problem?

**Edit**

I managed to edit the `activity_settings.xml` so that it uses an include tag.
However it is a bit overkill because it uses almost as much code as the code from `activity_generic.xml`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
       <include layout="@layout/activity_generic"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

At this point i'm not sure if its even possible to use `activity_generic.xml` instead of `activity_settings.xml` (portrait).

Comment: `I tried to use an include tag but it didn't work` Please elaborate how it didn't work. Update your question with relevant parts of the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the exact same layout and achieve the same.
However there are some built in features that android has and are a common practice.

By default android shall pick the layout files from the /res/layout folder,
for both landscape and portrait orientations.
However, you can make a /res/layout-land folder and place a layout file with the same name and make landscape related UI changes there.
Android shall automatically pick this layout file for the landscape orientation.

You can check this link for further details: [Android: alternate layout xml for landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode)

Comment: Yeah, I did put the layout-land in my example as well, see the (land) after activity_settings.xml. Unfortunately this will cause lots of duplicate layout-files for the portrait variant, cause it will mostly be the same.