# How to fill all screen with a tablelayout in landscape mode?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout, landscape-portrait

i'm using a TableLayout on my applycation. This is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scrollbars="none">

<include
    android:id="@id/action_bar"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_toolbar" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/action_bar">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And, i fill the table with Java code:

```
   TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
    TextView txt_plazo = new TextView(this);
    txt_plazo.setText(" Plazo ");
    txt_plazo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    txt_plazo.setTextSize(16);
    txt_plazo.setMinimumHeight(0);
    txt_plazo.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    txt_plazo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tbrow.addView(txt_plazo);

    TextView txt_saldoInicial = new TextView(this);
    txt_saldoInicial.setText(" Saldo Inicial");
    txt_saldoInicial.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    txt_saldoInicial.setTextSize(16);
    txt_saldoInicial.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    txt_saldoInicial.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tbrow.addView(txt_saldoInicial);

    TextView txt_parcialidades = new TextView(this);
    txt_parcialidades.setText(" Parcialidades ");
    txt_parcialidades.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    txt_parcialidades.setTextSize(16);
    txt_parcialidades.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    txt_parcialidades.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tbrow.addView(txt_parcialidades);

    TextView txt_interes = new TextView(this);
    txt_interes.setText(" Interés ");
    txt_interes.setTextSize(16);
    txt_interes.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    txt_interes.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    txt_interes.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tbrow.addView(txt_interes);

    TextView txt_total = new TextView(this);
    txt_total.setText(" Abono Capital");
    txt_total.setTextSize(16);
    txt_total.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    txt_total.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    txt_total.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tbrow.addView(txt_total);

    table.addView(tbrow);
    fillTable();
```

Etc...

All works fine but i'm trying to view the table in landscape mode, the problem is that the table don't fill all screen. In portrait mode looks good.

[image: landscape mode]

[image: portrair mode]

P.D: `android:shrinkColumns` and `android:stretchColumns` don't work for me.

Comment: Use `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content` for `layout_width` of your views

Comment: set android:layout_width="match_parent" to all three views HorizontalScrollView, 
ScrollView,
TableLayout.

Comment: Both methods don't work

Answer (score 0):

Use match_parent for your views.

Comment: Try to make layout for landscape separately.

Comment: But my table take all values from code, how i can edit only landscape mode if in the preview the layout is in blank?

Comment: you can create layout for landscape mode with same views as in portrait mode .  Refer this link for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode