# Problem with datepicker and timepicker

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

Hi i put the code of the examples in android developers in the same classe but i have a problem in this

@Override
            protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

```
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                            mDateSetListener,
                            mYear, mMonth, mDay);  

            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                        mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
                }
            return null;
        }
```

why i can't do this??

it only works with one case..

Answer (score 1):

when declaring static fields for DATE_DIALOG_ID and TIME_DIALOG_ID, set different values. eg. 
DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way: 
  [DateTime picker in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055509/datetime-picker-in-android-application/5268933#5268933)

Comment: i have the same but gives a error in the code that i posted. The error is duplicated case..

Answer (score 0):

**When using `switch`, its `case` can never be same, they must be distinct.**

Here `DATE_DIALOG_ID` and `TIME_DIALOG_ID` both are constants and it looks like they must be having same values. Check their values, if they are same then change it. I am sure changing their value will not change anything in your `DatePicker` or `TimePicker`.