# Android: timepicker and datepicker in the same dialog box

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog, timepicker

I am developing an app for android. I have created a timepickerdialog and a datepickerdialog, but the problem is, both of them run in different dialog boxes, which is not what the way I want my app to work :-S
Is there any way to create a single dialogbox with both time and date picker dialog boxes in it together?

Thx

Answer (score 17):

You can find a DateTimePicker implementation here:

http://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/

Comment: Can't believe that this answer has no upvote and not the accepted one.. +1 because it gave me exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: I create project by using this source , make some changes  and Migrating to Android Studio https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/datetimepicker

Answer (score 2):

I have created a custom Alert Dialog as in the [Google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog). I replaced the ImageView and the TextView with a DatePicker and a TimePicker. I changed the following line:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
```

with this:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_time, 
                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.datePicker));
```

For whatever reason the first gave an error, but the second worked. Anyway, I can use the two views in the same dialog window now.

Answer (score 0):

call time picker dialog in datepicker's update time method,It'll not be called at the same time but when you press datepicker's set button,Time picker dialog will open . The method is given in the answer of this link:
[DateTime picker in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055509/datetime-picker-in-android-application/5268933#5268933)