# IOS time picker in Android

Tags: java, android

I need to implement an IOS time picker with minutes and seconds in an Android app but I have no idea where to start, online I just found solutions that use `dialogs` but I don't want to use them. Is there any tip or library that could help me on implementing the picker?

Here's a screen of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: check it out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime picker in android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055509/datetime-picker-in-android-application)

Comment: these solutions uses dialogs.. I found nothing that implements it without dialogs that's why I asked for it

Comment: Read the docs I linked: `We recommend that you use DialogFragment to host each time or date picker.`. **As you know**, a DialogFragment, in that it **is a Fragment**, can also be used as a normal Fragment (hosted inside an Activity), instead of showing on a separate window.

Comment: @DerGol...lum ok thank you! i'll try with your solution

Comment: See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#DialogOrEmbed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not recommend trying to mimick the iOS behaviour, afterall each platform has it's own set of rules and guidelines. The iOS time picker is an iOS time picker, Android does things differently (as mentioned in some comments below your question, [tyically as a dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html).)

However, if you do insist on going down the iOS time picker route, [here is a popular library](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) people use called Android Wheel.

Well worth taking some time to read up on Android's [design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html) when you get chance.