# How to fix picker dialog that is cutoff in smaller screens?

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog, timepicker

In android application, I have used `TimePickerDialog` and `DatePickerDialog`. I want to develop this app in all different screen sizes.

The problem is, this dialog size is the same on all screen sizes. Dialog does not adjust its size as the size of the screen changes. So, on a smaller screen, the content of the dialog is cut off.

How can I adjust this dialog?

below is output I am getting in different size device. I even can't able to scroll in this dialog

[App output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVRMi.jpg)

[App output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epiah.jpg)

Code of DatePickerdialog:

```
 DatePickerDialog datePicker;

 editText_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(mActivity,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d) {               
                 //other code here
                }
            },yy,mm,dd);

         //allow only future dates
            datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate.getTimeInMillis());
            datePicker.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you add a picture of the lost content? Could you share your code as well?

Comment: I have added code. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

you can use these code block. if you will receive error you can write.

```
    private void dialogDatePickerLight() {
    Calendar cur_calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog datePicker = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    long date_ship_millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                }
            },

            cur_calender.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            cur_calender.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            cur_calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );

    datePicker.setThemeDark(false);
    datePicker.setAccentColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cyan_800_overlay));
    datePicker.setMinDate(cur_calender);
    datePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Title is here");

}
```

Comment: datePicker.setThemeDark() method is not available

Comment: @bhumivaghasiya device screen size very small. if above code not response for you you can use this answer for your device. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28291780/8738452

Comment: This is not solution of my problem.